# Add Code as branch or tag into my SVN and use it

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A friend of mine implemented features on the project but he had to work disconnected from the SVN repository. Now he sent me by FTP the results of his work. I wanted to integrate this as a branch or a tag to be able to work on it before merging it to the trunk.

I upload his code to the SVN (as a tag) but I can't use it in my workspace for "it shares no ancestry"

What am I doing wrong in SVN processes?

Answer (score 1):

Treat your friend's code similar to a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

1. Create a branch (from trunk) for his changes
2. Apply his changes to the branch
3. Merge the branch to your trunk

Comment: fascinating read ! thanks a lot !  But his 'libcomplex' is the project it self. This might have a strong consequence, no ? I can't forecast what exactly though

Comment: Should the code I am importing as the first vendor branch be in the workspace or can it be anywhere ?

Comment: I have followed the process (with Toitoise). Now I want to work on the newly created vendor branch (the one for customization). But it shares no ancestry with my working copy (there is the consequence I could not forecast, bummer). Isn't dangerous to checkout this branche ? (I know I am responding to myself but I hope you will be able to confirm some points one day : it is hard to learn alone all the time)